# Problem reading multiple serial ports using SerialDataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have two devices that stream data to my application.  One device that continually streams 9 byte data packets terminated with '\r\n' at a rate of 1 packet each 50 ms to COM1.  The second device sends a 38 byte packet terminated with '\r\n' to COM3 only when the device is triggered.

Each has a completely different SerialDataReceivedEventHandler and each runs in it's own dll puting them in different threads.

The COM1 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler always performs well.

The COM3 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler will perform well if no data is streaming into COM1.

However, when the COM1 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is operating and the COM3 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is operating, the COM1 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler fires immediately when data is available but the COM3 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler takes up to 12 seconds to fire when data is available.

Is the COM1 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler keeping the COM3 SerialDataReceivedEventHandler from firing? Or maybe something else is happening under the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler hood?  Any ideas?

Comment: Using some kind of USB version?  Run over it with your car, get another one from another supplier.

Answer (score 3):

By default, COM1 and COM3 both use the same interrupt line to signal when data shows up, assuming these are real serial ports. Can you configure one of the ports to be COM2 or COM4?  COM1 & COM3 both share IRQ 4 while COM2 & COM4 share IRQ 3.

You may be able to look at this with Device Manager (you can run devmgmt.msc to start it up).

Comment: COM1 is scale data input,  COM2 is being used for Label Printing output, COM3 & COM4 are Scanner data input

Comment: I have tried changing the interrupts on COM3 & COM4 in the device manager but it did not make any difference. If I run two instances of hyperterminal one reading from COM1 and the other reading from COM3 I do not see any delay in data received.   It seems to me that the problem lies with the SerialDataReceivedEventHandlers.

Comment: How is the CPU usage? Are you starving any threads? Are you doing any polling which is preventing other threads from running?

Comment: It looks like it ended up being the computer hardware. According to th emanufacturer the computer is using a crippled version of the IBM motherboard and BIOS and hence can't process the interrupts fast enough.  I added a MOXA serial to USB convertor and my code is processing all the serial input fine now.